# Hooking up HttpSelfHostServer with an ApiController

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple class `TestController` that derives from [ApiController](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller(v=vs.118).aspx) and handles `POST` Http requests. I also have an instance of [HttpSelfHostServer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.selfhost.httpselfhostserver(v=vs.118).aspx) that listens on `http://localhost:12357`

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.SelfHost;

namespace RestController
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:12357");
            using (HttpSelfHostServer server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config))
            {
                server.OpenAsync().Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to quit.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage PostMethodFactory()
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to connect the `TestController` to the `HttpSelfHostServer`. How do I make all `POST` requests to `http://localhost:12357` route into the `TestController` class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured this out. I just had to add the following line in `Main`

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("default", "{*url}", new { controller = "Test" });
```